# Can I add WiFi to an Arduino Uno using an ATWINC microchip?

Tags: arduino, pcb, integrated-circuit, wifi

Can I use an ATWINC15x0 microchip to add WiFi functionality to the Arduino Uno by just connecting the relevant pins together directly?

UNRELATED BACKGROUND, I recently began my journey into printed circuit board design and it's safe to say I'm just throwing things together blindly. My only real PCB education is that I took the Altium Designer Education Course that covered a shield board sesign for an Arduino Uno.

Currently I'm trying to recycle the ideas I learned from a previous Altium Designer Course to add WiFi functionality to the Arduino Uno using an *ATWINC1500-MR210PB1961* microchip.

According to the datasheet, the ATWINC models typically uses around 3.3V and a maximum 269mA current draw. I was hoping that I could simply connect the ATWINC chip's input voltage pin directly the Arduino Uno's 3.3V pin using pin headers. From there, using the same shield board approach that I learned from the Altium Designer Course, I'm thinking I could connect the remaining ATWINC pins to the Arduino using some more pin headers. I see that the 3.3V pin for the Arduino Uno can only supply ~150mA. Could I potentially add another current source separately to make up for the ATWINC current requirement?

Now obviously I understand from reading the "Schematic Design Info" section of the ATWINC data sheet that the chip's pins also require various resistors and coupling capacitors to filter out noise and stabilize voltage levels, so it wouldn't just be a true Arduino to ATWINC pin-to-pin connection. Assuming I take the extra components into consideration, what disturbingly obvious electronics/signal transmission detail am I grossly overlooking?

I've attached a couple pictures detailing what I believe the design could look like.

[ATWINC datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATWINC15x0-MR210xB-IEEE-802.11-b-g-n-SmartConnect-IoT-Module-DS70005304E.pdf)

Design schematic, AtWINC module top, series of pin headers bottom:

[image: Design Schematic, AtWINC Module Top, Series of Pin Headers Bottom]

Board design layout, no pins connected, pin header numbers start from left to right in picture:

[image: Board Design Layout, No Pins Connected, Pin Header Numbers Start from Left to Right in Picture]

Comment: yes, or you could switch to an arduino platform that already includes wifi like node-mcu.

Comment: 1) Arduino Uno has a 5V MCU, while ATWINC15x0 is a 3.3V module, you will obviously need level-shifter or pick a 3.3V MCU. 2) if you are intend to use the ATWINC15x0 as a WiFi module, you don't need to connect every pins to the host MCU, see the reference design on Datasheet on what need to be interfaced with host MCU.